# Calculating image acutance

Tags: image, image-processing

Is there a simple algorithm for calculating an [acutance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acutance) value (or sharpness) for a grayscale image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand it, the Accutance is the mean value of the [**Gradient Filter**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GradientFilter.html).

Example in Mathematica:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Relationship between brightness and the blurriness of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919517/relationship-between-brightness-and-the-blurriness-of-an-image/5919775#5919775)

The question's title is confusing, but the answer answers this.